# Как увеличить число в строке 01

Tags: php

Как увеличить число 01 в строке на 1, чтоб получилось 02.

```
$number = 01
$number++;
```

получается 2.

Comment: Все правильно. 02 это 2 и между ними нет никакой разницы. Если вам нужно выводить с нулем, то форматируйте вывод.

Comment: Эникейщик, разница есть. 0 в начале числа обозначает восьмеричную систему счисления.

Comment: я надеялся, что можно без форматирования вывода)

Comment: @Node_pro даже в этом случае между 02 и 2 нет разницы.

Comment: @ИгорьПетров если вам нужно отпечатать восьмеричный числовой литерал, то так и напишите в тексте вопроса. По значению числа 2, 02 и 0x2 и даже 0x00002 абсолютно равны друг другу и хранятся в памяти абсолютно одинаковыми битами

Answer (score 0):

Математические операции приводят переменную к типу `int`/`float`. Вам нужно из числа сделать строку и добавить префикс. Как вариант, можно использовать [`str_pad`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-pad.php)`:

```php
<?php

$number = 01;
$number++;

echo str_pad($number, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```